# Cannot change the startup splash screen

Tags: login, ubuntu-studio

I am using ubuntu studio 11.04. I've done `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop xubuntu-desktop  mythbuntu-desktop  kubuntu-desktop` etc. And my computer turn on screen changed to kubuntu and my log in screen turned to lubuntu. How can I change both back to ubuntu studio?

Answer (score 1):

The startup splash screen is called "**plymouth**".

If you change the plymouth theme, execute the below command with terminal.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth && sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Input the number of your favorite plymouth theme(ex. **ubuntustudio-logo.plymouth**), and <kbd>enter</kbd> .

After reboot your PC, then you can see the changed theme.